# Terraria cross platform help

Tags: terraria-mobile

I have Terraria for Xbox 360, Android, and PC (I'm in love with this game) but my brother only has an iPhone. The developers recently released a new update adding all the new console content and whatnot to the mobile versions.

Is it possible to cross platform any of my items with his iPhone so he doesn't buy it for nothing?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct:

**No**, you can't bring items from one version to the other. There is no way to get items from the pc version to the console version, or from console to mobile or any other combination.

Comment: Yeah im not good at explain lol. My brother has an Iphone and wants to join my game. I have terraria on my android device and also my xbox and pc. Is it possible for him to join my game with his iphone to any 3 of my devices?

Comment: Certainly impossible to join xbox and pc, I'm not certain about being able to join android from iOS. There is a chance that *might* work, but I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: Thank u. I just didn't want him wasting money for nothing.

Comment: @MatthewNicholasKennedy Looks like the only cross platform is PS3 to Vita

Comment: Yeah that stinks lol. I don't have ether

Answer (score 0):

With the new update of terraria 1.3 on mobile, you can take the 1.3.0 files from your PC save and transfer it to your mobile at *android/data/com.Terraria*, but it needs to be 1.3.0 equivalent.

***you can also us terrasavr to make your own 1.3 save [here](http://yal.cc/r/terrasavr/)***

Answer (score -3):

Android can connect to ios, but has to be the same client or whatever, so you can't have a hacked client without the other having it too.